# HDD filesystem suddenly changed to RAW and testdisk show Filesystem seems damaged

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, data-recovery, testdisk

One old PC which my dad uses suddenly didn't boot into Windows XP. So I get HDDs from it and put them into external HDD box. One of them is shown in Explorer but can't access it, it shows message: `You need to format the disk in drive before you can use it.` In diskmgmt.msc it is displayed as `RAW`. I found that `Testdisk` should help me with. After both quick and deep scan it showed me this one partition: [image]

Then I pressed `p` to list all files in partition but it showed me this: [image]

I haven't found any solution for this yet. Has anybody any suggestion?

For the second disk: Explorer didn't show me it and diskmgmt.msc said that it is unallocated. I haven't work on it yet, I will also appreciate any suggestions to this problem too.

Comment: [I would run Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) on the drive.

Comment: Before running Spinrite (great tool BTW) be sure to check your SMART stats. If the disk is approaching a failed state, you are better off using DDRescue to get an image off it before all is lost. Last time I ran spinrite on a damaged disk, it spent its last gasps trying to fix random bits on the disk surface, and as a result I could  not get the disk to function sufficiently to perform any further recovery tasks like imaging it to healfthy media. SpinRite does have a utility for reading SMART data.

Comment: @FrankThomas I checked SMART data in HDtune and it says it is OK, I doesn't understand it deeply but it just showed that state is OK. Now I run surface scan to know if disk is OK. now I'm somewhere in half and everything is fine. I didn't understood what spinrite do, I don't want to get data from disc, I want it working or look into it, get important data, format it and clean install new system.

Comment: ok, it sounds like spinrite is exactly what you want. it will reenforce the magnetic signal of every bit on your disk. I only bring up data recovery, because if the disk is failing, it might lose its partition the way you described.

Comment: So is anywhere any tutorial for Spinrite? If I understood you it has many functions and one of it (don't know yet whitch of them) is suitable for me to bring my disk filesystem back to NTFS. As I see I have to make bootable USB and run it when starting pc, then let it run on connected HDD.

Comment: @FrankThomas Ou, I checked SMART for wrong disk, my fault. Now I tried it for correct but it just showed that it is not available and surface scan found 1 damaged block yet and test is still in begginin :(

Comment: 1 bad block isn't worrisome, but if you see an increase in bad blocks in the near future, consider changing the disk. Bad blocks tend to grow exponentially to time, once you have more than a couple of them. Once the SMART test is complete, it should have checked every block, and you can evaluate the number then. Bad blocks are particularly nasty in that they both wear out the disk mechanically, but also destroy data while they are at it.

Comment: Test is over and there was "just" one bad sector. SMART data still n/a, I maybe use another software to see it. I also analysed 2nd HDD with Testdisk but same result (Filesystem seems damaged). I'm frustrated. Sitting here since lunch and haven't get access to single HDD :(

Comment: start with 'chkdsk /f' on the disk and if it still reports issues, use spinrite.

Comment: For first disk - chkdsk is not available for RAW drives.
For second disk - it is not possible to specify unallocated partition tu run chkdsk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of all failed attempts to get back lost partitions was RAID - on 2 disks were made 2 partitions but one partition was on both disks. Let say, I have two 200GB disks and partition C: of size 20GB is on disk 1 and partition D: of size 380GB is partly on disk 1 (180GB) and partly on disk 2 (200GB).

I found out this by placing disks back to PC and run Ububtu from USB. I made this also on my laptop but partitions still weren't accessible because of connection through 2 external HDD boxes (seems this option doesn't merge martition right).

So that's reason why I can't access disks when connect using external hdd box and also reason that any of recovery and partitioning and whatever software wasn't successfull.

Edification: Know things that you work with :)